# Where to find these fields in Github's GraphQL library?

Tags: github-api

I am trying to get these two fields.
required_pull_request_reviews.users.login and
required_pull_request_reviews.teams.name

from the original REST API:
/repos/{owner}/{repo}/branches/{branch}/protection/required_pull_request_reviews

But in GraphQL I cannot seem to find where this information is.

I have next to no experience with GraphQL, so it is quite possible that I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Hey. Could you give an example of the data you require? I do not think the exact fields are available from GraphQL however the context will help understand what the best next solution may be.